# Heat shield for where single-wall meets double-wall stovepipe

Tags: heating, woodstove

I'm installing a wood stove using an existing double-insulated chimney. My understanding is I need a heat shield anywhere the stovepipe comes this close to a wall, but I'm not sure what part I need to provide the shielding here.

The wall itself is a 24" stud wall that is relatively freestanding in front of the actual foundation which is block along that wall. It was clearly built with the sole intent of providing additional insulation - I will be working on this wall as well so if the answer is to just cut out more space for the stovepipe, that's okay too.

What part do I need to provide the heat shielding here? The hardware store couldn'tname the part, but he also knew that a shield was required here.

[image]

Comment: Is that a triple wall pipe going through the wall or a listed Zero clearance? It looks smaller than the pipes and boxes I used to use.

Comment: I don't actually have any information on the pipe in the wall/chimney (it's 7" pipe), short of the inspection I did of the interior of the pipe itself. Can I get around all of those concerns by providing a small air gap where it passes through the wall?

Comment: Think it might be called a wall pass though for stove/chimney pipe.  A double tube that gives an air gap between the chimney and wall.  Think you need a bigger hole.

Comment: @crip659 The pipe going through the wall is double insulated, so it (to my understanding) does not need a pass through, my concern is shielding the single wall pipe as it approaches the wall

Comment: did you cut the 2x4 ?

Comment: I did not - the double insulated chimney up to this wall was already installed. The work I plan to do on this wall is to pull down the vapor barrier, fix the sagging insulation, use a header board on this stud to transfer the load, and then put it all back together.

Comment: I would have some space I have installed a few pellet stoves and the 3 wall pipe I use requires 1” space from combustible materials. If the unit was in use I don’t see any heat issues so you may be fine, my jurisdiction requires triple wall for any floor ceiling or wall penetration.